# When using the substr() string function, Why is a litteral carriage return twice as long as a line feed character "\n"?

Tags: php, string, substr

When typing the following code ... (easily testable with [W3schools' editor](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_substr))

```php
<?php
$basecss = '.class {
    margin-bottom:0
}
/*1234567890';

$basemincss = ".class {\n\tmargin-bottom:0\n}\n/*1234567890";

echo substr($basecss,0,35).'*/';
echo '<br><br>';
echo substr($basemincss,0,35).'*/';
?>
```

... The results are :

```css
.class {
    margin-bottom:0
}
/*12*/

.class {
    margin-bottom:0
}
/*12345*/
```

So why does replacing a string's **return carriages** by **line feed characters** also reduces its length?

Comment: On windows end of line is `\r\n`, not `\n`. And I ensure that indentation is actually tab and not 4 spaces